# Utilizar pysal para calcular autocorrelacion espacial en datos vectoriales .shp

Tags: python

Estoy intentando implementar 'pysal' para poder calcular el indice de autocorrelacion espacial "Local Moran" de los puntos de un archivo vectorial .shp. Esto con el objetivo de realizar una limpieza de datos vectoriales a nivel del INLIERS.
Mi problema esta cuando debo de obtener la matriz de pesos W, para poder despues utilizarla como parametro de entrada de la funcion Moran_local del paquete pysal.

El codigo que utilizo es el siguiente:

```
import pysal
import numpy as np


f = pysal.open("soja.dbf")
y = np.array(f.by_col["DryYield ("])
w = pysal.knnW_from_shapefile("soja.shp", k=6)
lm = pysal.Moran_Local(y,w)
print lm
```

Alguien ha trabajado de esta manera y con este paquete en este tipo de datos?

Muchas Gracias

Ya he solucionado el problema
Era un problema en mi pc, dejo el código por si las dudas.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8

import pysal
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt




w = pysal.knnW_from_shapefile("soja.shp", k=4)
f = pysal.open("soja.dbf")
y = np.array(f.by_col["DryYield ("])

lm = pysal.Moran_Local(y,w)
local_moran = lm.Is
for i in local_moran:
    print i
```

Saludos y muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola Carlos, por favor, edita tu pregunta siguiendo esta guía: [mcve].

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema? ¿Te lanza algún error? ¿Te da un resultado inesperado? Las funciones las estas usando correctamente.  Si haces `print lm` obtienes el objeto solamente no datos, algo asi: `<pysal.esda.moran.Moran_Local object at 0x0000021746F72240>`